# Flutter: scoped model access in StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, dart, scoped-model

I have scoped model `lib/scoped_models/main.dart`:

```
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

class MainModel extends Model {
  int _count = 0;

  int get count {
    return _count;
  }
  
  void incrementCount() {
    _count += 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setCount(int value) {
    _count = value;
    notifyListeners();
}
```

And very simple app `lib/main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';
import 'package:scoped_m_test/scoped_models/main.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel<MainModel>(
        model: MainModel(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        )
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final MainModel _model = MainModel();

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _model.incrementCount(); // <-- doesn't work !!!
  }
  
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // _model.incrementCount(); // <-- doesn't work !!!
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, MainModel model) {
                return Text(
                  '${model.count}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                );
              }
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, MainModel model) {
          return FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              model.incrementCount(); // <-- only this works !!!
              // _incrementCounter(); // <-- doesn't work !!!
            },
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          );
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The problem that I can't access `MainModel` outside of `ScopedModelDescendant` widget.

How to call `MainModel` methods at the beginning of `_MyHomePageState` class?

I believe it is possible because I don't want to keep all logic just in `MainModel` class and call every method in `ScopedModelDescendant` widget because it would be very inconvenient if there were many nested widgets.

So, how to get access to scoped model in `StatefulWidget`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use Scoped Model as provider

- add `ScopedModel` just before the widget which use it (MyHomePage)
- use `ScopedModel.of<MainModel>(context)` to control the model
- use `ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>` to listen the model

The advantage of using this:

- You can access the same model in the descendants and share data easily
- rebuild widget as small as possible (only ScopedModelDescendant part will be rebuilt)

code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: ScopedModel<MainModel>(
        model: MainModel(),
        child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    ScopedModel.of<MainModel>(context).incrementCount();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
            ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
              builder: (context,child, model){
                return Text(
                  '${model.count}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _incrementCounter();
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Put MainModel as a Singleton

As your solution, you create MainModel once and make it final. This can be more simple like below:

**MainModel**

```
final MainModel mainModel = MainModel();

class MainModel{
  int _count = 0;

  int get count {
    return _count;
  }

  void incrementCount() {
    _count += 1;
  }

  void setCount(int value) {
    _count = value;
  }
}
```

**MyHomePage**

- `MainModel` even no need to extend Model or use notifyListeners becaue the widget use `setState` to rebuild

code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      mainModel.incrementCount();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '${mainModel.count}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _incrementCounter();
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After watching into my code for a while I realized how stupid simple it was to fix.

So, obviously there should be just one instance of `MainModel()` for all widgets and files of the project and for convenience it should be placed in scoped model file `lib/scoped_models/main.dart` like this:

```
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

final MainModel mainModel = MainModel(); // <-- create instance once for all files which require scoped model import

class MainModel extends Model {
  int _count = 0;

  int get count {
    return _count;
  }
  
  void incrementCount() {
    _count += 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setCount(int value) {
    _count = value;
    notifyListeners();
}
```

And then you can use `mainModel` instance anywhere you import the model `import 'package:<app_name>/scoped_models/main.dart';`

So that, this code will be valid `lib/main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';
import 'package:scoped_m_test/scoped_models/main.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel<MainModel>(
        model: mainModel, // <-- instance of model from 'lib/<app_name>/scoped_models/main.dart'
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        )
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      mainModel.incrementCount(); // <-- now it works !!!
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, MainModel model) {
                return Text(
                  '${model.count}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                );
              }
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, MainModel model) {
          return FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // model.incrementCount(); // <-- works !!!
              _incrementCounter(); // <-- now it's working too !!!
            },
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          );
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Despite that fact that is seems reasonable, it can be overwhelming as well for the first time due to lack of examples.

Comment: It is a little strange that you make your `mainModel` as a global singleton, why you need `ScopedModel` anymore?  You can simply use `class MainModel extends ChangeNotifier` and read/write it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for comment but I don't know how to implement your approach properly.

Comment: I try to explain it on the other answer. Let me know if you have any further question.